# mysql average of best three

Tags: mysql

I have pieced this together from sites online and it works but not completely, what i need it to do is take the top 3 results and average them but it takes ALL results, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
 SELECT i.NAME,
   e.comp,
   Round(Avg(c.phase1 + c.phase2 + c.phase3 + c.phase4 + c.phase5
             + c.phase6), 2) AS "Average Score",
   ( CASE
       WHEN compID = '7' THEN Concat(Round(Avg(
                                              ( (
       c.phase1 + c.phase2 + c.phase3 + c.phase4 + c.phase5
       + c.phase6 ) / 400 ) * 100), 2), ' %')
       WHEN compID = '5' THEN Concat(Round(Avg(
                                              ( (
       c.phase1 + c.phase2 + c.phase3 + c.phase4 + c.phase5
       + c.phase6 ) / 600 ) * 100), 2), ' %')
       WHEN compID = '3' THEN
Concat(Round(Avg(( ( c.phase1 + c.phase2 + c.phase3 + c.phase4 + c.phase5
                 + c.phase6 ) / 600 ) * 100), 2), ' %')
ELSE 'Unspecified'
END )                   AS "Average as Percent"
FROM   jos_practicedetail c,
   jos_comps e,
   jos_practice g,
   jos_members i
WHERE  e.compsid = g.competition
   AND g.practiceid = c.practicepid
   AND i.memberid = c.competitorid
   AND g.typeID = '2'
   AND Year(g.pdate) = '2017'
   AND (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   jos_practicedetail b
        WHERE  b.competitorid = c.competitorid
               AND b.practicepid = c.practicepid
               AND ( b.phase1 + b.phase2 + b.phase3 + b.phase4 + b.phase5
                     + b.phase6 ) >= (
                   c.phase1 + c.phase2 + c.phase3 + c.phase4 + c.phase5
                   + c.phase6 )) <= 3
GROUP  BY competitorid
HAVING Count(*) > 2
ORDER  BY competitorid,
      ( Avg(c.phase1 + c.phase2 + c.phase3 + c.phase4 + c.phase5
            + c.phase6) ) DESC
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the 'right' direction is normalisation.

Comment: What isn't normalised?

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, you can be sure that your design is flawed. In this instance, one could argue that a further flaw is that there isn't a separate column for gender, and perhaps even a column for distance, and a column for I/O - but that might be taking it too far. !?!

Comment: I see what you are saying and when I had everything in one table it worked fine took the top three scores of each competitor and averaged them perfectly. now that i have tried to normalise them it doesn't work it just averages all the scores?

Comment: If you have a new question, feel free to ask one!

Comment: is it possible to get the above query to only select the top three scores?

Comment: I'm not going anywhere near that data model! Give me a normalised model, and I'll happily see what I can do (no promises though)

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated the code is that any better? can you help with my problem?

Comment: No, not in my book.